# protractor Unexpected identifier for selector

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, protractor

I was trying to select a element using protractor

```
<span data-ng-if="check.medium === 'AIR'" class="ng-scope">Clean air</span>
```

command I used to extract element is

```
$('span[data-ng-if="task.medium === 'AIR'"]')isDisplayed().toBe(true);
```

I was getting a failed expectation error, Im really not sure what could be the fault

Any help is much appricaiated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *escape the single quotes* inside the selector. And, you are missing the `expect()` call and a dot before the `isDisplayed()` call:

```
expect($('span[data-ng-if="task.medium === \'AIR\'"]').isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
```

I would though, if possible and applicable, rely on the element's text instead:

```
expect(element(by.xpath("//span[. = 'Clean air']").isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
```